# How to compile servlet and existing package for tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

Sorry, I'm very new to java servlets.  I have an existing java package (that I built and ran in eclipse, did not compile) that runs fine on its own.  I have a sample servlet in another folder.  I'd like to compile all of this so it can run on a tomcat server.  I know a `javac` will compile a class, but which one do I compile if this is a servlet AND another package?  Do I have to list ALL classes, can I list just the package names?  Do I need to create a single .war file or multiple .war/.jar files?

Sorry, my use of Java up to now has been in Eclipse.  I can compile and run a single class, but a complex environment with multiple packages with a target platform of tomcat is leaving me lost as to 'where I begin.

Comment: Look for the `-cp` option to set the classpath.

Comment: Thanks, but what is the recipe I should be doing here?  IE:  1) compile external package, 2) compile servlet and get result of XXX, 3) deploy to tomcat via YYY.  Unsure what the high-level steps should be

Comment: You can combine 1) and 2) if you wanted to. You'll have to package the compiled code appropriately into a WAR (specific format) so that it can be deployed on Tomcat (or other container).

Comment: If I combine 1 and 2, do I have to list all of the classes in the other package, or will the classpath simply include all of those .java files?  Also, if I have many classes in the same package as my servlet, do I need to list all of them as well or does a classpath of '.' tell the compiler to look in the local directory?

Comment: With `javac`, all source files that you need compiled need to be specified (you can use ant style *.java patterns to match every file) but also need to provide any dependencies directly with `-cp`. Those can be in `jar` files or `.class` files directly.

Comment: So I can compile all source files with a *java, set a flag to export to a .war file, then 'load' that war into tomcat?

Comment: Yes. You might find it easier to use a build system like Maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do following:

1) First project should be able to create a jar file. 
2) In the Second project ( Servlet) ,you can right click on the folder of the dynamic web project( I assume you have created it as DWP) , and click Properties --> Deployment assembly. Here you can add reference to other projects and external jars. 
3) Once you are able to do this setup, you can try 'exporting' your second project as war.

This is just a naive way to start as I do not want you to overwhelm with complexity of multi module development for a beginner. But will point you to m2e plugin in eclipse for something called "Dependency Management" . This plugin will help you manage much more bigger and complex projects. Do spend some time on http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-project-with-maven/ to understand maven and how to it works before attempting Maven in eclipse with m2e plugin.